# How do I apply z-index on my text to float it over my image

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am trying to float text over an image and cannot seem to get the text to sit on top of the image.

If I had an image and a text block inside a div. What CSS would be needed to make the text work as I planned.

Here is my code without the css:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="text-area">
        <i class="icon ion-md-exit"></i>
        <h2>TEXT</h2>
        <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>

    <img class="bg-image" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg">
</div>
```

If you could vertically align the text area too, that would be a massive help.

Thanks!

Comment: `z-index` will not take effect unless the element has a position setting that is NOT *`static`*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I was doing this I would do it one of two ways.

You can use the image to declare the height of the element, then place the text area over the top like this:

```
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

.text-area {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;

    text-align: center;
}

.bg-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="text-area">
        <i class="icon ion-md-exit"></i>
        <h2>TEXT</h2>
        <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>

    <img class="bg-image" src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg">
</div>
```

Or set the height of the box and use a background image like this:

```
<style>
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;

    background-image: url(https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/images/ic/720x405/p0517py6.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.text-area {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;

    text-align: center;
}

.bg-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}

</style>

<div class="row">
    <div class="text-area">
        <i class="icon ion-md-exit"></i>
        <h2>TEXT</h2>
        <p>TEXT</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Fantastic, it seems my issue was with the .row part, I didn't even need the z-index, thanks for your help!

Comment: Great, I have recommended a few changes to your question that will hopefully stop the downvotes.